# I have array of images for the background on my app. How can I make them change automatically with interval 1 sec?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage

I have array of images for the background on my app. How can I make them change automatically with interval 1 sec?

```
let myImagesArray = [UIImage(named:"1.png"),UIImage(named:"2.png"),UIImage(named:"3.png")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **animationImages**.

```
//if you programmatically create your image view
let iv=UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
view.addSubview(iv)

//assign your images to your image view
let myImagesArray=[UIImage(named:"1.png"),UIImage(named:"2.png"),UIImage(named:"3.png")]
iv.animationImages=myImagesArray
iv.animationDuration=1*myImagesArray.count
//to make it loop infinitely
iv.animationRepeatCount=0 
iv.startAnimating()
```

Comment: xcode made me change it to :  super.viewDidLoad()
        let iv = UIImageView()
        let myImagesArray = [UIImage(named:"1.png"),UIImage(named:"2.png"),UIImage(named:"3.png")]    but it still doesn't work.
        iv.animationImages = myImagesArray as! [UIImage]
        iv.animationDuration = TimeInterval(1 * myImagesArray.count)
        //to make it loop
        iv.animationRepeatCount=0
        iv.startAnimating()    }

Comment: What does not work exactly? I assume you put an UIImageView to display your background images? Do you do it programmatically or from the storyboard? You can initiate your images in viewDidLoad but maybe you should call iv.startAnimating() in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Also @ЮлияКордюкова maybe you should start with iv.animationRepeatCount=10 to see if it works, then replace with iv.animationRepeatCount=0

Comment: i did it this way:  backgroundImageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "IMG_8667")!, UIImage(named:"IMG_8658")!, UIImage(named: "IMG_8670")!]
        backgroundImageView.animationDuration = 1.0
        //to make it loop
        backgroundImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0
        backgroundImageView.startAnimating()

Comment: @ЮлияКордюкова Great, does it loop infinitely? If it works don't forget to mark my answer as the right one please ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTimer

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimer/1412416-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval

```
var iNSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0,target: self, selector: Selector("methodName"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func methodName() 
{
   //This Method Execute after every 60 sec.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTimer to detect 1 sec is over or not.. This code will take random image from array and put it in the imageView in background

**Swift 3.0**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //SNIP, some code to setup the windos.   
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.handleTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    return true
}

func handle(_ timer: Timer) {
        // Hanlde the timed event.
    var rnd: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(imageArray.count)
    var imageName: String? = (tips[rnd] as? String)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}

    - (void) handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
        // Hanlde the timed event.

        uint32_t rnd = arc4random_uniform([imageArray count]);

        NSString *imageName = [tips objectAtIndex:rnd];
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]
    }
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    //SNIP, some code to setup the windos.   
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.handleTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    return true
}

func handleTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
        // Hanlde the timed event.
    var rnd = arc4random_uniform(imageArray.count)
    var imageName = tips[rnd]
    imageView.image! = UIImage(named: imageName)!
}
```

Comment: thank you! anything else simpler?  i am total beginner.

Comment: is it for swift ?